# usages and nuances of 'enjoy'

Tags: vocabulary

> I ***enjoyed*** going to Sydney at Christmas.
>  (The Cambridge
>   Grammar of the English Language)

“Enjoy” in the example seems to have meaning of perfection, for the adjunct, ‘at Christmas’ is not ‘at Christmases’. While, “I enjoy dancing” and “I still enjoy good health” ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enjoy)) seem to have imperfective meaning, that is, “I enjoy dancing as a habit”, “I enjoy good health from the past till present all the time,” respectively. Can ‘enjoy’ really be used as both meanings of ‘enjoying once’ and ‘enjoy all the time or repeatedly’ –– for example, can “I enjoyed going to Sydney at Christmases” be possible?

Comment: I think your version would be *on Christmases*.

Comment: Probably this is not enough to answer, but _enjoy_ alone doesn't mean _enjoy once_ or _always enjoy_: It depends from the context. Simple Present is used for an action habitually done, but "I enjoyed our time in New York" doesn't say if I enjoyed it once, or I enjoyed it all the times I went to New York. If I want to make clear I am referring to a specific occasion, I could say something similar to "I enjoyed the last time we went to New York."

Comment: @snailboat I'd say ***for** Christmases* :) ***On** Christmases* suggests repeated departures on Dec. 25th. Of course OP is on the same side of the date line, so it's less of a problem for her.

Comment: I think you're mixing up viewpoint aspect and lexical aspect. *Enjoy* is an *activity* verb by lexical aspect -it has duration but no endstate- but when it is cast in the perfective viewpoint aspect wit the "simple past" construction it is seen from the outside, as a whole. Simple past recategorizes repeated and habitual actions, in the same way, depicting that as a 'closed' series, like a string of pearls.

Comment: In any case, the adjunct (regardless of preposition) modifies *going* rather than *enjoyed*.

Comment: I'd use the singular _Christmas_, even if it was more than one Christmas. "I enjoyed going to Sydney for Christmas [each year]." (The "each year" can be omitted if it is inferred by other context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [snailboat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat) commented, you'll want to stick with “on” when referring to a day.

> I enjoyed going to Sydney on Christmases.

Or, if you want to take [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb)'s advice to specify that you were actually *in* Sydney while enjoying these Christmases (and not initiating your travel on that day), you could write:

> I enjoyed going to Sydney for Christmases.

**Both sentences above are grammatical, and would be a perfectly good answers to a question such as “What did you like most about your childhood?”**

---

In a situation where it's not clear over what span of time these Christmases occurred, you may want to use a different construction, to avoid ambiguity. For example:

> I enjoyed going to Sydney for Christmases when I lived in New Zealand.

Or even just:

> I enjoyed going to Sydney every Christmas when I lived in New Zealand.

---

As [kiamlaluno](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/95/kiamlaluno) notes, there's nothing special about the word being “enjoy” in this case. You could just as well use a different word (like “loved” or “detested”) in its place and all the same rules would apply.

[StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) also offered a beautiful explanation that I can't risk anyone missing because it was a comment:

> “Enjoy” is an *activity verb*—it has duration but no endstate—but when it is cast in the perfective “simple past” construction it is seen from the outside, as a whole. Simple past recategorizes repeated and habitual actions, in the same way, depicting that as a “closed” series, like a string of pearls.

Comment: Q. no.1) `I enjoyed going to Sydney for Christmases.`- Does it mean that the speaker went to Sydney on every Christmases year after year say from 2004-2008? Q. no.2) StoneyB's last comment that you quoted, does it mean that the simple past holds the same usage as "used to"? Like, `I played football every year till 2008` and `I used to play footbal till 2008`- Do both of them mean the same?

Comment: @Mistu4u  #2:The habitual reading is not effected by the simple past but by the phrase "every year". The simple past characterizes that habit as "over and done with". See the tag-wiki article on [aspect](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

Comment: @Mistu - One can say "I enjoyed going to Sydney for Christmas" – even with just the singular "Christmas" – and it can mean **either** the speaker went year after year, **or** it can be refering to just one Christmas. More context would be needed to eliminate the ambiguity.